# Django MTTP: Максимальный уровень вложенности

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Здравствуйте

Код модели:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Название")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Слаг")
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True, verbose_name="Родительская категория")
#parent = models.ForeignKey('self', models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Родительская категория", null=True, blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    l = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
    l2 = [x.name for x in l]
    return ' / '.join(l2)
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    lvl = self.level if self.level else 0
    if lvl < 6:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise AssertionError("Максимальная вложенность: 5")
class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['name']
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Категория"
    verbose_name_plural = "Категории"
    #ordering = ["name",]
    index_together = ["id", "slug"]
```

Мне нужно ограничить максимальный уровень вложенности.
Пробовал так:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lvl = self.level if self.level else 0
        if lvl < 6:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise AssertionError("Максимальная вложенность: 5")
```

Но в данном случае при создании новой записи self.level всегда будет None, т.к. экземпляр модели еще не создан. Пробовал через "parent.level" и через "parent.get_ancestors()" получить родителей - не выходит, пишет что имя "parent" не существует (т.к. экземпляр только регистрируется)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ограничить уровень вложенности правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить через через обращение к "parent" как к аттрибуту "self" а не как к переменной:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        max_indent = 5
        lvl = self.parent.level if self.parent.level else 0
        if lvl < max_indent - 1:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Максимальная вложенность: %i" % max_indent)
```